# new values appear after numpy concatenate

Tags: python, numpy, split, concatenation

I load data from netcdf file. Original data contains some values of 1.e+15, which I define as Nan:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np

t = Dataset('temperature.nc', 'r').variables['t'][0]
ind = np.where(t==1.E15)
t[ind] = np.nan
```

Now I want to shift the data for another longitude coordinate, so I do split and concatenate:

```
#first split data 
a1, a2 = np.split(t, 2, axis=2)
# print out max, min values of a1 and a2
print a1.max(), a1.min()
print a2.max(), a2.min()
# then concatenate with another order (a2 before a1)
new = np.concatenate((a2, a1), axis=2)
# print max, min value of new array after concatenating
print new.max(), new.min()
```

However, I got the results on the screen:

```
313.69 181.438
313.69 181.407
```

and

```
1e+15 181.407
```

it means new array after concatenating contains again values of 1E15, which I don't understand why. Can any body explain me what did I do wrong. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are working with different datasets - ```temp``` and ```t```?

Comment: @wwii: sorry, It was a typing mistake. I worked with the same dataset. I corrected the typing mistake already. Please see the update above. Thank you

Comment: Can't reproduce - ```a = np.array([1.e15, 2, 3]); ind = np.where(a == 1.e15); a[ind] = np.nan -->> array([ nan,   2.,   3.])```.  Probably a floating point problem as Marcus Müller suggests or the values are not exactly 1.e15.  Maybe use [```numpy.isclose```](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) for the condition.

Comment: @wwii: Thank you. But I still don't understand why `a1.max()` and `a2.max()` don't give me values of 1.e15. For details please see my comment to Marcus's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a floating point comparison; 1.00000000001e15 != 1.000000000000e15; so this won't generally work. Use something like `np.where(t>=1e15)` instead.

Comment: You're right. But since `np.where(t==1.e15)` does not work, the values of 1.e15 still stay in the array `t`. Then I don't understand why after splitting, `a1.max()` or `a2.max()` does not give me these values?